# Turn off commands in installed packages for Django

Tags: django

I was wondering if there was a way to disable commands that come from an installed Django package that I do not control.

For instance:

cities_light is installed and has its own manage commands. I'd like to make those commands unavailable in the ./manage.py command list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to remove the command from the command list.

You could [override a commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/#overriding-commands) and replace it with a command that doesn't do anything.